# Exercise 5.1.8 in Vellemann, "How to Prove It"

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently working on Velleman's book "How to Prove It" and got stuck at exercise 8 in Chapter 5.1. The exercise is:
"Suppose *f* : *A* → *B* and *g* ⊆ *f*. Prove that there is a set *A'* ⊆ *A* such that *g* : *A'* → *B*."
I tried to let *A'* = *A* but failed to show that g is a function from *A'* to *B*. What set would work for *A'* and how can I proceed to find such a solution? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You would need first of all to see what your text says about the definition of a function $f.$ Some texts say a function $f$ is a collection of ordered pairs having certain properties. Then at least it would make sense to write $g \subseteq f.$ Then go from there...

Comment: Try $A' = \text{domain of } g$.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! First of all Velleman's definition of a function:
"Suppose F is a relation from A to B. Then F is called a function from A to B if for every a ∈ A there is exactly one b ∈ B such that (a, b) ∈ F. In other words, to say that F is a function from A to B means:
∀a ∈ A∃!b ∈ B((a,b) ∈ F).
To indicate that F is a function from A to B, we will write F : A → B."

Comment: Would this work? -:
Let *A’* = Dom(*g*). Suppose *a* ∈ *A’*. Then we can choose some *b* ∈ Ran(*g*) such that (*a*,*b*) ∈ *g*. Suppose (*a*,*b*) ∈ *g*. Since (*a*,*b*) ∈ *g* and *g* ⊆ *f*, (*a*,*b*) ∈ *f*. Since (*a*,*b*) ∈ *f*, it follows that *a* ∈ *A* and *b* ∈ *B*. Since *a* was arbitrary, *A'* ⊆ *A*. Since *a* ∈ *A’*, *b* ∈ *B* and (*a*,*b*) ∈ *g*, *g* is a relation from *A* to *B*. Suppose *c* ∈ *B*. Suppose (*a*,*c*) ∈ *g*. Since (*a*,*c*) ∈ *g* and *g* ⊆ *f*, (*a*,*c*) ∈ *f*. Since *f* is a function, (*a*,*b*) ∈ *f* and (*a*,*c*) ∈ *f*, it follows that *b* = *c*. [...]

Comment: [...] Thus ∃!*b* ∈ *B*((*a*,*b*) ∈ *g*). Since *a* was an arbitrary element of *A’*, we can conclude that *g* is a function from *A’* to *B*. Thus we can conclude that there exists a set *A'* ⊆ *A*, such that *g* : *A’* → *B*.

Comment: Define $p_A: A \times B$ by $p_A(a,b)=a$ for all $a \in A,b \in B$. Try to show that $A’= p_A[g]$ is as required. This is well defined as $g \subseteq f \subseteq A \times B$ etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for your reply! What do the square brackets mean in your term? Unfortunately, this notation is new to me.

Comment: @pahohu set image. If $C \subseteq X$ and $f:X \to Y$ is a function, $f[C]=\{f(x)\mid x \in C\}$ is a subset of $Y$ etc.

Comment: Begin by showing that for any subset $g$ of any relation $f$, $g$ is a relation, and $\mathrm{dom} \  g \subseteq \mathrm{dom} \  f$, and $\mathrm{ran} \  g \subseteq \mathrm{ran} \  f$.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! You all helped me to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy you described in the comments is correct:  Let $A' = \text{dom}(g)$ and then prove that $g \subseteq A' \times B$ and $\forall a \in A' \exists!b \in B((a,b) \in g)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help! I’m a huge fan of your book that put me in the place to understand how a proof functions and to appreciate its beauty and fun! I’m deeply thankful for this resource and am very eager to work my way through.